# How to only get one li in your bootstrap navbar to move to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am learning how to code with html and am trying to create a navbar to have some li on the right side and some on the left. Using bootstrap I can seem to find out how to move contact and only contact to the right side of my navbar. Does anyone know how to do that? I tried looking at other answers on this site and cant figure it out. Would I have to make the last one its own ul?

I have tried using float right and justify content end but it only works in the ul class and moves everything over. Same with ms-auto. If I put it down in the li class nothing changes. I have tried adding padding too but nothing moves. I just want to know how to move contact to the right side of my navbar and thats it not the About, My Account, and Login. Please ignore my html file names I know I have to update them.

Here is my code:

```
`    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/circle_r.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item float-left">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="tenant.html">Login/Sign-Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="proprietor.html">My Account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the "Contact" link to the right side of the navbar by adding a class to the ul element and using CSS to align the elements. Here's one way to do it:

Add a class to the ul element, for example: . The ml-auto class is from Bootstrap and will align the elements to the right.

Add a CSS rule to your stylesheet to change the justify-content property of the class you added to the ul element. For example:

```css
.ml-auto {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Your updated code would look like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/circle_r.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="tenant.html">Login/Sign-Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="proprietor.html">My Account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Ok so I tried that and nothing moved. Would that be because I can't override something in the bootstrap css? I know what you are trying to tell me but I dont know why it isn't working. Also would that move all my links to the right instead of just one? Maybe I typed something wrong too. I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `position: absolute;` to move the element to the right side of the navbar. I added a class `contact` to the `li` element so that css can be applied. Give the parent `position: relative;` as that will be the container the `contact li` is being responsive to. You can ignore the flex css as that was mainly for me to quickly align the links in a row. You can adjust the padding and spacing as needed.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.contact {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item float-left">
    <a class="nav-link" href="tenant.html">Login/Sign-Up</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="proprietor.html">My Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item contact">
    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```